# $P(h\leq k)=P(t \leq k),\forall k\in \mathbb{R}$ implies $h=t$

Tags: self-study, measure-theory

Consider the measurable space $(A,\mathcal{A})$. Let $h,t:A\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be mesurable functions. Show that If $P(h\leq k)=P(t \leq k),\forall k\in \mathbb{R}, \forall P$ probability on $(A,\mathcal{A})$, then $h(x)=t(x),\forall x\in A$.

As far as I understand, it says that random variables with the same distribution functions for all possible probabilities are equal.

It holds that for all $k$ and $P$,

$$\int_{(-\infty,k]}h \,dP=\int_{(-\infty,k]}t \,dP \iff \int_{(-\infty,k]}(h-t) \,dP=0 \implies h-t=0 \text{ a.e. on } (-\infty,k].$$

I'm unable to go further.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: It does not assert that random variables with the same distribution functions are equal.  (This is definitely untrue.)  It asserts that random variables that have the same distribution functions *for all possible probability measures* are equal.  In light of that, could you explain what your "a.e." ("almost everywhere") terminology means, given that there is no fixed probability measure in evidence?  BTW, please add the [tag:self-study] tag to these exercise questions.

Comment: @whuber Oh, that is true. It does not make sense to write $h=t$ a.e. in this case.

Comment: This question is also posted to math.SE.  Please see our [help/on-topic] in relation to cross-posting (toward the bottom of the page)

Answer (score 0):

In its present form, the subject line of this question says:

> $P(h\leq k)=P(t \leq k),\forall k\in \mathbb{R}$ implies $h=t$

As stated, that is false, as we may see by taking $(h,t)$ to be uniformly distributed in the square $[0,1]^2.$ In that case, $P(h\le k) = P(t\le k)$ for every $k\in\mathbb R,$ but $\Pr(h=t) = 0.$

But in the body of the question, you say for every probability measure $P.$ So let us suppose that for some $x\in A$ we have $h(x)\ne t(x).$ Let $P$ be the probability measure that assigns probability $1$ to the set $\{x\}.$ No generality is lost by assuming $h(x)<t(x).$ Let $k$ be some number between $h(x)$ and $t(x).$ Then we have
$$
P(h\le k) = 1 \ne 0 = P(t \le k).
$$

Comment: I like the idea, but I think it founders at the point where you implicitly assume $\{x\}\in\mathcal{A},$ which is not always the case.  This could use elaboration.  Consider replacing this by a consideration of the set where $h$ and $t$ differ: that is guaranteed to be measurable.

Comment: @whuber : ok, This needs somewhat more work. The sets $\{x\in A: h(x)\le k\}$ and $\{x\in A:t(x)\le k\}$ are measurable. One should try to do something with that.